# Social sharing link with frontmatter variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to put a markdown frontmatter variable in my social sharing URL in chain.

Does not work.

```
computed: {
linkedin() {
      return (
        'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true' + https://www.example.com + 
        this.$route.fullPath +
        this.blog.title +
        this.blog.summary
      )
    }
}
```

and

```
<a :href="linkedin" target="_blank">Li</a>
```

I dont get to see what I want to share. Only error message with no details.

I have a VueJS app!

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? Please be more specific.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 - How specific? Error message shows with no details. Must be something wrong with my syntax?